# (Co)limits in the category of diffeological spaces vs. category of smooth manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, smooth-manifolds, generalized-smooth-spaces, diffeology

I am wondering which (co)limits that exist in the category of smooth manifolds are preserved by the inclusion into the category of diffeological spaces? Are there any results that allow us to determine which (co)limits will be preserved? Are there any examples where the manifold (co)limit differs from the corresponding diffeological (co)limit, and the latter is more "right" or "wrong" from a geometric perspective?

I have just recently picked up the book [Diffeology](https://doi.org/10.1090/surv/185) by Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour, so I am not very familiar with the theory yet.

([crosspost to math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231273/colimits-in-the-category-of-diffeological-spaces-vs-category-of-smooth-manifo))

Comment: All limits are trivially preserved, since a diffeological space is determined by the maps from manifolds into it.  Since every diffeological space is the colimit of all the manifolds mapping into it, there is a colimit that is not preserved iff there is a diffeological space which is not a manifold but has a reflection in the subcategory of manifolds.

Comment: As Martin Brandenburg mentioned on MSE, non-Hausdorff manifolds give examples of colimits that are not preserved.  It seems plausible to conjecture that any Hausdorff diffeological space that has a manifold reflection is already a manifold.

Comment: @user59001: Why do you post this on mathoverflow after having received an answer on math.stackexchange? Could you please at least leave a comment there?

Comment: I appreciate your answer on math.se, but I posted the question here to see if anyone else had something to add. I figured that there would be more people interested in diffeology here than on math.se. Eric's comments are an example of something I was hoping to hear, for instance.

Comment: A counterexample to the conjecture in my previous comment: let $M$ be any manifold and let $X$ be $M$ equipped with the diffeology generated by smooth paths.  Then the identity $X\to M$ realizes $M$ as the manifold reflection of $X$ (by [Boman's theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Boman%27s+theorem)), is a homeomorphism, and is not a diffeomorphism unless $\dim M\leq 1$.

Comment: Since you are discussing reflections of diffeological spaces in the category of smooth manifolds, I assume that you mean that smooth manifolds form a reflective subcategory of the category of diffeological spaces? If so, do you happen to have a reference that discusses this? I haven't been able to find any mention of this fact.

Comment: Manifolds certainly do not form a reflective subcategory, but some individual diffeological spaces still have reflections (i.e., an initial object in the category of manifolds under them).

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference to some text or article where this notion of "reflection" is discussed? When I tried to look it up I just found articles on reflective subcategories and functors which reflect (co)limits.

Comment: I believe that Iglesias-Zemmour has several books on diffeological spaces, so I edited in a link to a likely guess.  I hope that was correct, but, if not, then feel free to change it.